# DFS Algorithm consistently finds path with less vertices than maximum

Tags: c++, recursion, graph, depth-first-search, directed-graph

I'm solving a programming problem with dfs. The tldr is as follows:
There are n cows at coordinates x, y. They can communicate to others within their radius of "voicability" p. Just because cow a can communicate to cow b, doesn't mean b can communicate back if it doesn't have sufficient p. If a message starts at any cow, what is the greatest number of cows it will be able to reach? Cows can relay messages from one to another. Ex. If b can hear a, and c cannot hear a but can hear b, b can relay info from a to c, so 3 cows hear the info in this case.
Here is a sample input:

```
4
1 3 5
5 4 3
7 2 1
6 1 1
```

First row is N, following rows are a cow's x, y, and p. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int n;
int best=0;
int cnt=1;
struct cow {
    int x, y, p;
    bool visited=0;
} cows[201];
bool adj[201][201];
bool access (int a, int b) {
    return pow(cows[b].x-cows[a].x, 2)+pow(cows[b].y-cows[a].y, 2)<=pow(cows[a].p, 2);
}
void dfs(int cow1) {
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        if (cnt>best)
        best=cnt;
        if ((!cows[i].visited)&&(adj[cow1][i])) {
            cnt=cnt+1;
            cows[i].visited=1;
            dfs(i);
        }
    }
    return;
}

int main () {
    cin>>n;
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        cin>>cows[i].x>>cows[i].y>>cows[i].p;
    }
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        for (int j=1; j<=n; j++) {
            if (i!=j) {
            if(access(i, j)) {
                adj[i][j]=1;
            }
            else {
                adj[i][j]=0;
            }
        }
        }
    }
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        cows[i].visited=1;
        dfs(i);
        cnt=1;
        for (int j=1; j<=n; j++) {
            cows[j].visited=0;
        }
    }
    cout<<best;
}
```

I'm not quite sure where the issue is, but I am sure it is within the dfs function, and not within the creation of the adjacency list. My code works only for the sample case. I'm essentially doing dfs on all n cases of starting cows for the message.

Comment: What does it mean that your code only works for the sample case? Does it throw an error? If yes, which one?

Also the first thing I see is that you are initializing your array in a questionable manner. Instead of going `cows[201]` right after your struct, consider using the user provided `n` to initialize the array in your main function with the right size and pass the array as an argument.
Also in C++, array enumeration starts at 0 and goes until n-1. Since you gave your array a static size this might not yet have lead to an error, but it would if you really initialized 201 cows.

Comment: not an error, it just outputs the wrong answer

Comment: The rest looks fine to me.. maybe someone else will see it. But do fix your array please. You also reset the array starting at 0 in the for loop on the 6th last line (while you start at 1 everywhere else) and are accessing an attribute on an object which is not defined. This kind of stuff leads to undefined behaviour in C++. But I don't think it is necessarily falsifying your results. Just start at 0 everywhere and go until n-1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is simple. You measure the longest path length (cow count actually). But the question is different, it is how may cows are reachable. Consider the case of three cows of which one can be heard by everyone while the others are voiceless. Your program will answer 2 (unless I missed another error) as that’s the longest chain, but the right answer is 3 (it is the count of cows `visited`).

Comment: I just tested my code and indeed it does output 2, while the answer is three. However, I'm not quite sure why the longest path length is different from the amount of reachable cows. Isn't that the same thing?

Comment: One cow’s voice may reach *several* cows at once